# From the production database how to change int field to char

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-10

From the production DB I need to change a field from int to char.

When I tried in local I lost all the data which is stored in the field.

What is the solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you change the type of field `field_name`, Odoo rename the original `field` to `field_name_moved0` and create a new one with name `field_name`, If you have access to the database you can set the value easily by a simple query:

```sql
-- just make sure you cast the value of field_name_moved0 to varchar
update your_table_name set field_name = field_name_moved0::varchar where field_name_moved0 is not null;
```

**Note:** If you change the type of field again, the name will be `field_name_moved1`.